# Cannot import existing collection from firebase to BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, firebase-extensions

I'm using the firestore-bigquery-export extension for Firebase.

I have successfully got a collection syncing to BigQuery. I have also successfully implemented my required custom schemas uploaded to BigQuery using npx @firebaseextensions/fs-bq-schema-views as per the extension documentation.

I am having trouble export/importing pre-existing data using npx @firebaseextensions/fs-bq-import-collection

Using all the same inputs I used in the config of the extension, I get the error:

```
Error unlinking journal file /Users/tim/.npm/_npx/12469/lib/node_modules/@firebaseextensions/fs-bq-import-collection/lib/from-idriver-app events incoming-to-ideliver-cloud_ideliver_app_incoming_raw_changelog after successful import: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink '/Users/tim/.npm/_npx/12469/lib/node_modules/@firebaseextensions/fs-bq-import-collection/lib/from-idriver-app.events.incoming-to-ideliver-cloud_ideliver_app_incoming_raw_changelog'
```

I suspect my Collection path is where I am failing, but no matter how I format it, I get the same error.

I have tried:
idriver-app events incoming
idriver-app\events\incoming
idriver-app/events/incoming
idriver-app.events.incoming
and even
idriver-app_events_incoming

Any help appreciated.